# How to solve this c# syntax puzzle?

Tags: c#, .net, logic

Can someone give me the solution for the following code puzzle?
A solution was given but could be more than one solution.

```
// this code compiles
IAnimal animal= new Dog();
animal.Eat();

// this code doesn't compile
Dog animal = new Dog();
animal.Eat();
```

How should the class definition look like so that the above code blocks, in separate scopes, compile(first one) and don't compile(second one) ?

Comment: *this code doesn't compile* - what is the compiler error?

Comment: If IAnimal can eat () and Dog is IAnimal then Dog can, per definition eat ().

Comment: @Domysee - they aren't saying their code doesn't compile - they are asking how to write code such that the above two lines produce the desired compile/not compile behavior.

Comment: @pstrjds oh right. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using *explicit* interface implementation:

```
class Dog : IAnimal {
    void IAnimal.Eat(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

As opposed to implicit interface implementation:

```
class Dog : IAnimal {
    public void Eat(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    void IAnimal.Eat() { }
}



IAnimal animal = new Dog();
animal.Eat(); // <---- OK

Dog animal2 = new Dog();
animal2.Eat(); // <---- COMPILE ERROR
```

Comment: Some explanation of why this answers the question would help the OP understand this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error on the second line is caused because the class `Dog` *explicitly* implements the `IAnimal` interface like this:

```
class Dog : IAnimal
{
    void IAnimal.Eat()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this case, you get the compile error on your second line because you cannot call `Eat` unless you're working with an instance of `IAnimal` because it's essentially a private method in `Dog`.

To fix the error, you either need to cast your instance back to an `IAnimal` like I showed you above, or you can *implicitly* implement the interface like this instead:

```
class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to produce code that would do that, not how could I call the code so that it will work.  They don't have any code - notice this line from the question - "How the classes definition should look like so that the above code blocks, in separate scopes, to compile(first one) and to not compile(second one)"

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution (`IAnimal` being interface and `Dog` being a class implementing that interface explicitly) is already provided in other answers.

Here are some other ways I can think of.

All they are based on `IAnimal` being a (poorly named) class like this

```
public class IAnimal
{
    public void Eat() { }
}
```

(A) Solution based on class defining an **implicit conversion operator** (note that defining a conversion from class to interface is prohibited, that's why it's important `IAnimal` to be a class/struct)

```
public class Dog
{
    public static implicit operator IAnimal(Dog dog) { return new IAnimal(); }
}
```

causes the following compile error in the second snippet:

> Error  CS1061: 'Dog' does not contain a definition for 'Eat' and no extension method 'Eat' accepting a first argument of type 'Dog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(B) Solutions based on **base method hiding**. Although in C# we can't hide the base method by providing in a derived class another method with different signature (because it will be treated as **overload**), we can do that by using a **field**, **property** or **event** with incompatible signature.

For instance

```
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    new public event Action Eat;
}
```

generates

> Error  CS0070: The event 'Dog.Eat' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Dog')

or

```
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    new public Action<int> Eat;
}
```

generates

> Error  CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'obj' of 'Action'